# Alert user of in-browser event when window minimized

Tags: javascript, notifications, minimized

I have a requirement where we need to alert the user of some event that happened in the browser even if the window is minimized. In browser we use toasts from toastr and this works great if the user is in the browser window already. We also have html5 notifications so in that case this isn't a problem, but many users will not necessarily have that enabled.

If the window is minimized it would be awesome if the browser taskbar item in Windows would start flashing or on Mac - bouncing. I tried to do a `window.focus()` for when the event comes through, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: This exactly what [the Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) is for.

Comment: Good old `alert` did this once for some browsers. Luckily no more.

Comment: @kapep In chrome it still does.

Comment: I'm already using the Notification API as I said in my question... Yes alert still brings focus back, but that's too intrusive. All I was looking for is something to flash the taskbar item

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers implement the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification). Here is an example:

```js
(function() {
  var button, output;

  function scheduleNotifyTheUser() {
    output.innerHTML = "Stand by…";
    setTimeout(notifyTheUser, 1000);
  }
  
  function notifyTheUser() {
    output.innerHTML = "Ding! You have a message!";
    new Notification("Something Happened", {
      body: "You should totally check this out!"
    });
  }
  
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    button = document.getElementById("gobtn");
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML = "Requesting permission…";
    Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
      if (permission !== "granted") {
        output.innerHTML = "Notifications disabled.";
        return;
      }
      button.addEventListener("click", scheduleNotifyTheUser);
      output.innerHTML = "Ready.";
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<button id="gobtn">Make something happen in one second from now</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: For some reason, when the window is minimised, there is a 7-8 seconds delay until the notification is displayed (I'm using chrome). Any idea why?

Comment: Most likely because the window is not in focus. The browser is being nice and slowing the page down when it is not in the forefront (being used) and so it's chance to perform operations will be diminished. Least I presuming that is the case since I don't know your code. If you need more resources from the OS then a back grounded webpage then your looking at making a native desktop app. Node-webkit might be an option if you want to use HTML/JavaScript for a desktop app.

Comment: Yes these are the desktop notifications... very nice except I'm already using these. I was asking for something other than this. Something that would simply make the taskbar item bounce or flash. Guess there is nothing though